# 'bzero' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I already included <"stdio.h">

using this function

```
bzero(&server, length);
```

but the compiler says

> error: 'bzero' was not declared in this scope

`

Comment: and why do you expect `bzero` to be declared? there is no such function in stdio required by the standard.

Comment: I think it works only in linux/mac os? not windows?..

in this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Emuw71lozdA I follow the codes correctly for UDP programming in c, but seems not working in windows.


they included
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <netdb.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
then it works on linux using bzero().

Comment: @AldwaneLaytonBayarasViegan: That's indeed not working in Windows/C++. Even on Linux, it is poor C++ code. (Note that C and C++ are two distinct but similar languages)

Comment: if you follow the posix link it says that it is included in `<strings.h>` not `<stdio.h>`.http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bzero.html.   Any how you should not use this function any more, as it has been deprecated. Better to use `memset` in its place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`bzero()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bzero.html) is not part of the standard library, it belongs to POSIX.

It's actually deprecated (note the **LEGACY** in the manual) now, so consider using `memset()` instead.

Comment: in C++ `memset` should be a last resort. If `server` is not an array then `server = {};` would be good. If it is an array then `fill( begin(server), end(server), T{} );`.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to run some old code, and got the error. I have just inserted this after my imports:

```c
#define bzero(b,len) (memset((b), '\0', (len)), (void) 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `<unistd.h>`
For me that's work for bzero and read at the same time.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why `unistd.h` is the correct header for `bzero`? Is it stated somewhere in the standard?

Answer (score 0):

you should include <string.h> .